# Limitation on requests for an Ad / Adset / Campaign history from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I currently want to get the full history of an Ad account on the Facebook side. Having read the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-activity
I expected to get all the events done in this account but found that I could only get one week of data. Something that is not indicated in the documentation.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to read the Graph API docs. In this case, pay attention to the [time-based pagination](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#time) part. You can specify the `since` parameter (which expects a Unix timestamp, more on it in the link above) to specify the start of the data you are requesting.